# How to forward contents in System Logs to different location in Red Hat?

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, suse

I would like to forward all the entries in the Linux Red Hat system logs containing "MyAPP" to this location:

```
/global/temp/
```

I was able to do this with SUSE but now our company has switch over to Red Hat and I have no idea idea how to do this.

For SUSE, the system log is located here:

```
/var/log/messages
```

The SUSE config file:

```
/etc/syslog-ng/syslog-ng.conf
```

Inside the SUSE config file:

```
filter f_MyApp     { match('^ssh-myapp:'); };

destination MyApp { file("/global/temp/ssh-myapp.$R_YEAR$R_MONTH$R_DAY.log"); };
log { source(src); filter(f_MyApp); destination(MyApp); flags(final); };
```

Would anyone know how to do this in Red Hat and which config file to edit?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `rsyslog` in RHEL there are options for sending logs to different files based on pattern matching. Some versions of RHEL come with rsyslog preinstalled while newer version might not as RedHat is pushing Journal as the default in systemd. With newer systems relying on only Journal you can still safely run rsyslog along side it as stated in `/usr/share/doc/systemd/README.logs`.

`dnf install rsyslog`

Here is an example of valid syntax you can put in `/etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf`

```
if $syslogtag startswith "postfix/anvil" or $msg startswith "statistics:" then {
    -/var/log/mail/postfix_stats
    stop
}

if $programname == "dovecot" and $msg startswith "auth-worker(" then {
    -/var/log/mail/dovecot_auth
    stop
}
```

Documentation Here:

https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/rainerscript/control_structures.html

https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/filters.html

https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/properties.html